# Github Actions: Workflow doesn't start on pull_request made by another workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have such GHA configuration:
Workflow to make a PR -> on: pull_request workflow to run tests
The second workflow doesn't start, when PR is made by "Workflow to make a PR". When I made PR manually or close/reopen PR from first workflow, second one start correctly.
Do you know where can be an issue, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> [By default](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow), when you use the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN` to perform tasks, events triggered by the `GITHUB_TOKEN` will not trigger a new workflow run. This prevents you from accidentally creating recursive workflow runs. If you do want to trigger a workflow from within a workflow run, you can use a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead. –
> GuiFalourd